# Do android photo's store compass information in metadata, if not how could it be done?

Tags: java, android, compass-geolocation

Just wondering , is there a way of storing the compass information of your phone when you take a photo,

Ideally the direction the person is facing when the photo will be recorded.

How would i go about implementing this in android

## Edit added

the ExifInterface does not store data based on the compass direction when a photo is taken.

How could i go about storing it with the photo?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this type of data would be stored in EXIF tags in the image, take a look at `android.media.ExifInterface`.